# Status messages with AJAX

Tags: ajax, status-messages

I'm making an AJAX call in drupal 7 via the standard AJAX Framework. My  problem is that when a status message is set by the AJAX callback, it is simply lost (or displayed at the next reload of the page). How can I display the status messages right after the AJAX callback has finished running, without reloading the page? Is there a module for that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can render the status messages and send them as anohter AJAX command.

For example:

```
$commands = array();

// Add other commands

$commands[] = ajax_command_prepend('div#ajax-status-messages-wrapper', theme('status_messages'));

return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
```

At least this is the way I solved this problem when I faced it.

Comment: You Are A Saviour!!! :D Thankyou so so much.

Comment: What is the use of theme('status_messages') in there?

Comment: @Bebang Bakikang render the status messages, returning HTML code with the current status messages.

Answer (score 10):

For Drupal 8 it's

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();    
$status_messages = array('#type' => 'status_messages');
$messages = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($status_messages);
if (!empty($messages)) {
  $response->addCommand(new PrependCommand('.your_selector', $messages));
}

return $response;
```

Answer (score 4):

For Drupal 8 form with AJAX, answer by Tim Bozeman worked, but messages were showed up with no styling. This is what worked for me:

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
drupal_set_message($action);
$form['messages']['status'] = [
  '#type' => 'status_messages',
];
$response->addCommand(new InsertCommand(null, $form['messages']));

return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

for me

```
$commands[] = ajax_command_remove('div.messages');
$commands[] = ajax_command_after('#main-content', theme('status_messages'));
```

worked. where #main-content is standard, and maybe needs to be customized for your theme's acutal messages position. (maybe you have to change the second method to **ajax_command_append()** or another)

Answer (score 0):

I had this originally:

```
\Drupal::messenger()->addMessage($this->t('Form Submitted Successfully'), 'status', TRUE);
$allMessages = \Drupal::messenger()->all();
$html = \Drupal::service('renderer')->renderRoot($allMessages);
$response->addCommand(new AfterCommand('div[data-drupal-messages-fallback]', $html));
```

But $html was always "". After reading answer from Tim, I added this:

```
$allMessages['#type'] = 'status_messages';
```

after retrieving all the messages.. and it worked. Odd that ->all() wouldn't include that.

Answer (score 0):

it's now much more easier :

```
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$response->addCommand(new MessageCommand('Example of status message.'));
```

Get all information on this article: https://www.drupal.org/node/3086403

Answer (score 0):

If you're here because in Drupal 8 / 9 you're trying to clear validation error messages upon successful form submission, here's what worked for me (with thanks to [rémy for the Drupal 7 inspiration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51759/status-messages-with-ajax#answer-96406)):

```
// Remove any validation errors from previous submission.
$response = new AjaxResponse();
$selector = '.messages--error';
$response->addCommand(new RemoveCommand($selector));

return $response;
```